# Java TimerTask with time, delay and period

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want to schedule my program to run between 9:00 AM to 10:00 AM and it should run for every 10 seconds during the specified interval. I am using method `scheduleAtFixedRate()`. This method allows either delay, period or firstime, period. But I need firsttime, delay, period.

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TimerDemo extends TimerTask
{
public TimerDemo()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, new Date(), 2000);
}
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("This is the new Task");
}
public static void main (String args[])
 {
    new TimerDemo();
 }
}
```

Can some one help me on this.

Comment: What would the two mean? Could you just add them?

Comment: Is all 3 really needed ? Period is mandatory. But other two appears interchangeable. Like can we not use delay as difference between current time and first time or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could stack them together, i.e. first use start some Dummy task using

```
void java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)
```

From this dummy task you can then invoke the main task using

```
public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,
                                long delay,
                                long period)
```

Doing so should allow you to control firsttime (via the dummy task) and delay and period using the main task. This could look something like this...

```
    package sorting;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerDemo 
{

    static class StarterTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Dummy task invoked");
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new MainTask(), 10*1000, 60*60*1000);
        }

    }

    static class MainTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Main task invoked");
        }

    }

    public TimerDemo()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        timer.schedule(new StarterTask(), date.getTime()); 
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new TimerDemo();
    }
}
```

Note you could certainly use another "stacking" approach when you combine it with the

```
cancel()
```

function

Answer (score 1):

I have refined version of solution for this problem. This Will run your task based on the input start time and end time. I used joda time. you can use time in 24 hour format.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
public class NewTimerDemo extends TimerTask
{ 
  static Timer timer  = new Timer();
  static String startTime = "12:28";
  static String endTime = "12:30";

@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Running your Task");

    DateTime dt = new DateTime().withTime(
            Integer.parseInt(endTime.split(":")[0]), 
            Integer.parseInt(endTime.split(":")[1]), 0, 0);
    if(!dt.isAfterNow())
    {
        System.out.println("Here to cancel");
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    DateTime dt = new DateTime().withTime(
            Integer.parseInt(startTime.split(":")[0]), 
            Integer.parseInt(startTime.split(":")[1]), 0, 0);
    System.out.println(dt);
    Date date = dt.toDate();
    timer.schedule(new NewTimerDemo(), date, 5*1000);
 }
}
```